# $(window).on('load', function () не работает после перезагрузки страницы на телефоне

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть сайт с прелоадером - https://ilya07092000.github.io/
Прелоадер работаем 1500мс, после чего становится display: none;

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
        $('.loader').delay(1500).fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

После перезагрузки сайта на ТЕЛЕФОНЕ, прелоадер не выключается, на компе все работает ок, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать после него

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('.loader').hide();
  }
```

Если будет скрывать сразу, то

```
setTimeout("$('.loader').hide()",1500);
```

И ещё можете попробовать вместо delay использовать в своем коде setTimeout

Comment: Спасибо, мне помог второй вариант)